# Kendo UI change chart label background color based on custom function

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a bar chart which renders two bars. The color of one bar is determined by a function, but the label background color for that bar renders black. I need it to render the same color returned from the `colorStatus` function.

```
    $("#foo").kendoChart({
        dataSource: source,
        legend: {
            labels: {
                font: "0.8em Segoe UI"
            },
            position: "bottom"
        },
        chartArea: {
            background: "transparent",
            height: 150
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "bar"
        },
        seriesColors: [ colorStatus, "darkcyan"],
        series: [
            { name: "YTD Actual", field: "YTDActual" },
            { name: "YTD Budget", field: "YTDBudget" }
        ],
        valueAxis: {
            visible: false,
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            format: "{0:C}",
            font: "0.8em Segoe UI",
            template: "#= dataItem.AccountName # <br/> #= kendo.toString(value, 'c') #"
        }
    });

    function colorStatus(e) {
        if (e.dataItem.YTDBudget < e.dataItem.YTDActual) {
            return "red";
        }
        return "green";
    }
```

I've tried passing in a color and colorStatus to the legend > labels > background object as well, but still the legend label background renders black.

*Clarification* the label for the series YTDActual is rendering black. YTDBudget renders darkcyan.

Answer (score 0):

Many kendoChart properties may be functions

To set the background of a series item label to the color of the series item you could do something like:

```
series: [{
    { name: "YTD Actual", field: "YTDActual" },
    { name: "YTD Budget", field: "YTDBudget" }
    labels: {
        background: function (item) {
            var series = item.series;
            return series.data[item.index].color;
        } 
    }
}],
```

I didn't replicate your code to try it, but this works fine off a local dataSource.